Building a Statistically Sound ML Model
Silent reader here in the statistics substack. One thing I've learned is that many "default" machine learning practices are being challenged due to fundamental statistical mistakes. This has been enlightening but also somewhat overwhelming.
I’m looking for a resource or example that illustrates an almost "ideal" data science workflow—specifically for creating a classification model—where even experts in statistics would find little to no issues.
The diversity of approaches is fascinating, but it can also be confusing. For context, I’m working on a multiclass classification project for the healthcare/pharma domain. However, with the new knowledge I’ve gained, I’m now second-guessing my ML pipeline at every step.
I’d greatly appreciate any recommendations or guidance.

Do you want to use the result for predictive classification, or are you interested in inference?

For classification sir, because this will be used for scoring a campaign. I am just overwhelmed by conflicting ideas.

Also, I have around 1.5k rows only with an initial feature set of 300.

Thanks. 1,500 rows and 300 features sound like you really want to limit the number of features to use, and use regularization.

Avoid workflows and pipelines, just focus on understanding the data (the processes that generate the data) and understanding the tools and evaluation metrics etc.  As you gain that understanding, you will be able to decide for each application what steps are required.  Workflows are good when you start out, but they get limiting after a while (IMHO)

'many "default" machine learning practices are being challenged due to fundamental statistical mistakes': This is a bit of harsh generalisation. I don't think Statistics practitioners are fundamentally "more correct" than AI/ML practitioners. They are people who cut corners in both fields. The replication crisis isn't because people used MLPs where they shouldn't, it is (primarily) cause people used t-tests where they shouldn't. Don't get me wrong, there are AI/ML horror shows out there, but Stats practitioners are no data Messiahs either.

@usεr11852: IMO, many "default" statistical practices should be... challenged... as well, in some fields more so than in others.

I agree with both @usεr11852 and Stephan, ML may be more prone to this as ML tends to use more complex models than are used in traditional statistics, with more to go wrong, so "default" practices can be more risky.  However, there are more practitioners of traditional statistics, so bad "default" practices tend to be more deeply ingrained.  However IMHO there is no conceptual difference between statistics and ML (if done correctly), it is mostly a difference in computational expense - at the end of the day, fundamental understanding is the key to avoiding problems.

This is a very broad question, and any specific answer will depend heavily on your use case. However, I believe some general points can be made.

Acquire subject knowledge. Talk to experts in the field. Talk to the consumers of your ML model. Yes, also talk to statisticians and data scientists in the field. Possibly talk to lawyers.
You want to talk to the experts in order to understand the main drivers of whatever you want to model. You want to talk to users to understand what they are hoping to get out of your model, and how they want to apply it, and what level of sophistication they will bring to their consumption of your model (all of which can have an impact on how you want to model). The statisticians can tell you what challenges the data are likely to present, from missing data across prevalences to selection and other biases. Lawyers can tell you about the regulatory and data protection landscape you need to keep in mind: in healthcare, you typically have to care about privacy, and if you are in medical/pharma product development, the FDA and similar governmental agencies may have stringent requirements.

Once you have acquired subject (and subject-informed statistical) knowledge, you can plan how to collect data.
Do not start collecting data before acquiring knowledge, because likely enough you will invest resources and time in collecting the wrong data, useless data, biased data from convenience samples, or flat-out illegal data in terms of data protection.
Also, in talking to statisticians discuss how to limit your data collection. The subject matter experts will have many suggestions about which predictors are relevant... but this way lies overfitting. Consider whether predictors have a strong, medium or weak relationship to the outcome, and also how easy or cheap it is to collect predictor data. Also, consider whether predictors are available at the point where you want to run your models, based on your discussions with the end users: if you want to build an early screening model, blood data may simply not be reasonably available.

Once you have planned how to collect data, take that plan back to the experts and have them comment on your plan. While they are taking your plan apart, you will learn even more about the subject matter. This is a Good Thing.

Once your data collection plan has stabilized, you can start collecting data.
While you are collecting data, take a look at it. You will find problems nobody told you about. Discuss these with the stakeholders from point 1 above to understand how to address the issues.
Then collect more data.

Once you have data, split it into training, testing and validation sets. If you suspect strong time influences, then split by time so you don't "learn from the future".

Your training data is your playground. The target is to choose and fit a "reasonable" number of models based on this training data, and then to apply these to the testing data. (This is specific to this being for predictive classification.)
Yes, this is not hard and fast guidance. Essentially, you want to avoid overfitting to the testing data. If you fit a million models to your training data, apply them all to the testing data and finally choose the one model that performed best, you will likely not have a model that generalizes well, because you indeed overfitted to the testing data. Note (a) that complex tools like DL can do this "trying millions of models" thing "under the hood", that (b) this situation is exacerbated by having little data, and that (c) many competitions run by Kaggle and similar likely do exactly this - so use competition results with care.

Within the training dataset, do whatever is useful. This will depend on your situation: you may need to address missing data using multiple imputation, or you may be able to just do casewise deletion. You may want to transform or combine data, or not. You may want to regularize your model, or not.
It may make a lot of sense to further subdivide this training data into a "training-training" set and a "training-testing" set to simulate the production environment. If you model and predict into the "training-testing" set, analyze the predictions. Do they fail in some systematic way? If so, this should motivate you to change the models.
While you are analyzing and working with your training data, keep talking to the people from step 1. Bounce ideas off them. Discuss your findings with them, especially surprising ones. Discuss any systematic failures of your models.

At some point, you have a "reasonable" number of models, which you can apply to and evaluate on your testing data. You should really limit the amount of work you do with your models and your testing data, because any back-and-forth at this point heavily risks overfitting.
Ideally, just evaluate once and decide whether to pick a top-performing model or alternatively to combine multiple models. Selection makes for more easily interpretable models, combination usually yields better performance.
And yes, this is an idealized description. Likely enough, you will find some serious issues on your testing data, which very much suggests you should go back to the training data and modify your models. Just keep in mind that overdoing this will result in overfitting.

Once you have your final model (or combination of models), apply it to the validation set to get an idea of its performance under "production" conditions.


All of this will need to be modified based on your specific situation. I would say that the key aspects are (a) it is important to understand the context and the data and (b) you never have enough data and time, so you will need to time-box your analysis and accept that you will not be able to do as much as you would like to do - so again, it is important to understand which are the most important aspects, and deal with them first.

I suspect you would be a fan of Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies textbook. He discusses pieces of that book on his Statistical Thinking blog. I also like his Controversies in Predictive Modeling and Machine Learning video. Again, the video is largely based on his book.
The full data science workflow is broad subject better suited for a textbook (or an entire postgraduate degree) than a Stack Exchange post. Harrell's book gets into coniderable detail about where common perceptions go awry and what improves upon them.
What Harrell's book does not discuss in detail are modern methods of machine learning like random forests and neural networks. You have to go elsewhere to get thorough explanations of those. However, I find it important to understand generally good statistical practices and statistical theory no matter what regression technique is applied. Theorems do not stop being true just because you wrote import tensorflow as tf.

The online version of the Regression Modeling Strategies text is available here. It lack the refined flow of the full text (which I strongly recommend), but in some places it has more up-to-date information. (+1)
